# WCF Error : The caller was not authenticated by the service in WsDualHttpBinding

Tags: winforms, wcf, exception

Am currently developing a Publish subscribe wcf service. Trying to run the subscriber(winforms app) on one machine and the service(running on winforms app) on another machine. When connecting, it gives the SecurityNegotiationException follow by the error message

> The caller was not authenticated by the service

Client Config :

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IPostingContract" clientBaseAddress="http://192.168.1.101:8000/wcfClient/" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="False"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.101:8888/PostingContract/Posting"
      binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IPostingContract"
      contract="IPostingContract" name="WSDualHttpBinding_IPostingContract">
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Service Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IPostingContract" clientBaseAddress="http://localhost:8000/wcfClient/" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:00:20"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

If I change the security mode for client side to Message, which is the original mode, i get a timeoutexception even after waiting for 5minutes. After reading through most of the questions asked by other people, most people recommend putting none.

please note that this is WSDualHttpBinding and not basic bindings.